# Dismissing a popover view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

In the app i have i display popover view when i press an + bottom. I then have the person put in some information and then they need to use a uiimagepickercontroller within the popover view to add a picture to the information. I then need the person to be able to press a done button and have the popover view close. My problem is that in the story board I am using a popover segue to make the view a popover view but to be able to display the uiimagepickercontroller, the view controller is just a regular view controller. I can not seen to find a way to get everything to work and be able to minimize the popover by pressing the button. Currently everything works until i try to press the button to close the view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try dismissViewControllerAnimated?

```
@IBAction func doneButtonTapped(AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Comment: Wow thank you I was looking for this. Question - how does it know that you are dismissing the presented popover without specifying something like `self` or doing any type of casting on the topmost `viewController`?